# NullPointerException on .setAdapter in a Fragment with ListView not work

Tags: android

I work in Android App ListView working under a layer fragment by fragment, but I can not make it work. I got an error that says:

> setListAdapter method (ListAdapter) is undefined for new Runnable () {}

I do not know what I need to change to get this working.

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    private String url = "http://192.168.2.150/54_tower/Json_Tower.php";

    private static final String J_NAME = "t_name";
    private static final String J_NUM = "t_num";
    private static final String J_FLOOR = "t_floor";
    private static final String J_CLASS = "t_room_class";
    private static final String J_TEACHER = "t_room_teacher";
    private static final String J_TOILET = "t_toilet";
    private static final String J_MAP = "t_map";

    private static final String D_NAME = "NAME";
    private static final String D_NUM = "NUM";
    private static final String D_FLOOR = "FLOOR";
    private static final String D_CLASS = "CLASS";
    private static final String D_TEACHER = "TEACHER";
    private static final String D_TOILET = "TOILET";
    private static final String D_MAP = "MAP";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";

    Activity act;
    ListView ListView1;

    JSONArray products = null;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList;

    public static FragmentA newInstance(int page, String title) {
        FragmentA fragmentFirst = new FragmentA();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("someInt", page);
        args.putString("someTitle", title);
        fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
        return fragmentFirst;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_tower, container, false);

        // Permission StrictMode
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        new LoadAllData().execute();

        final ListView lisView1 = (ListView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        lisView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Map.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            // Intent intent = act.getIntent();
            // act.finish();
            // startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    class LoadAllData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);

            Log.d("All JSon: ", json.toString());

            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // Log.d("TAG JSON",""+data.toString());

                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(D_NAME, c.getString(J_NAME));
                        map.put(D_NUM, c.getString(J_NUM));
                        map.put(D_FLOOR, c.getString(J_FLOOR));
                        map.put(D_CLASS, c.getString(J_CLASS));
                        map.put(D_TEACHER, c.getString(J_TEACHER));
                        map.put(D_TOILET, c.getString(J_TOILET));
                        map.put(D_MAP, c.getString(J_MAP));

                        MyArrList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    // Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    // NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    // i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    // startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            final ListView myList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(
                    R.id.listView1);

            act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ListAdapter sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                            MyArrList, R.layout.tower_column, new String[] {
                                    D_NAME, D_NUM, D_FLOOR, D_CLASS, D_TEACHER,
                                    D_TOILET, D_MAP }, new int[] { R.id.Name,
                                    R.id.Num, R.id.Floor, R.id.Room_Class,
                                    R.id.Room_Teacher, R.id.Toilet });
                    myList.setAdapter(sAdap);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Here is the LogCat: [Image LogCat](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1391126094516281&l=bf3f9518a8)

Comment: Please include the log in your question instead of a photo link. We want questions to still be useful for future visitors, and links get broken. It's also very difficult to read, text can't be copied and pasted, and some people may have firewall restrictions at work that prevent them from seeing your image since it's hosted on Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to post to the UI thread onPostExecute since you started the task on the UI thread. Remove the `runOnUIThread` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of runOnUIThread just create a Handler and post this runnable to that handler.

Also create the listview as a field of this class and get reference of it in onCreateView or onActivityCreated. I think its causing nullPointerException. The important thing is that you should make Listview as field of the fragment class instead of having it inside local scope of methods.